# Add Control M character in a text file

Tags: linux, unix, control-m, dos2unix

Hi I am trying to add Control M character in a text file using Putty. I tried to do Ctrl-v Ctrl-M but as soon as I do this it goes out of putty to my desktop home.Can anyone please tell me how to add Ctrl M character in a file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to use the `unix2dos` utility:

```
$ unix2dos myfile.txt
```

Comment: This will add control m character in the file?

Comment: @PramodBhat Yes, it will. At least it did for me on RHEL7.

Comment: This does not work on RedHat 8.5. Any idea why?

Answer (score 4):

In `vim` in the insert mode and type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>m</kbd>.

Comment: This is what I tried,as soon as I do this it comes back to homepage

Comment: You can enter unicode characters in vim. Press and type CTRL-v and then the hex code of the character

Comment: Hey I pressed Ctrl V followed by enter and it worked.but how?? Any idea?

Comment: Windows-based text editors will have a special carriage return character (CR+LF) at the end of lines to denote a line return or newline, which will be displayed incorrectly in Linux (^M).

Answer (score 1):

In Vim, in the insert mode, Ctrl-V x##, where ## is the hex code of the character. In case of Ctrl-M the combination is Ctrl-V x0d.
You can see the hex value of a character under cursor if you type :as
command.